# Django is annotating wrong Count (possibly duplicates?)

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-orm, django-annotate

I have a model `ChatMessage` that has a field `sender` which is a `ForeignKey` to `User` model.

I'm trying to annotate a number of all the `ChatMessage` objects that haven't been read (eg. have `seen_at__isnull=True`).

For a given user, there is only one sent message with `seen_at__isnull=True` but `Django` returns 11.

```
User.objects.select_related(...).annotate(
            sent_unread_messages=Count('sent_chat_messages',
                                       filter=Q(sent_chat_messages__seen_at__isnull=True))).get(pk=1234).sent_unread_messages
```

do you know where is the problem?

EDIT:

```
class ChatMessageManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self) -> models.QuerySet:
        return super().get_queryset().select_related('sender', 'recipient')

    def as_sender_or_recipient(self, user) -> models.QuerySet:
        return self.get_queryset().filter(Q(sender=user) | Q(recipient=user))

class ChatMessage(BaseModel):
    objects = ChatMessageManager()
    sender = models.ForeignKey('users.User', verbose_name='Odosielateľ', null=True, blank=True,
                               on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name='sent_chat_messages')

    recipient = models.ForeignKey('users.User', verbose_name='Adresát', null=True, blank=True,
                                  on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name='received_chat_messages')

    content = models.TextField('Obsah')
    attachment = models.FileField('Príloha', null=True, blank=True)
    attachment_filename = models.CharField('Názov prílohy', null=True, blank=True, max_length=128)
    meta = models.JSONField(verbose_name='Meta', null=True, blank=True, help_text='must be JSON')
    seen_at = models.DateTimeField('Prečítané o', null=True, blank=True)



class CustomUserManager(UserManager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super().get_queryset().select_related('staff_profile', 'client_profile').annotate(
            sent_unread_messages=Count('sent_chat_messages',
                                       filter=Q(sent_chat_messages__seen_at__isnull=True))).annotate(
            received_unread_messages=Count('received_chat_messages',
                                           filter=Q(received_chat_messages__seen_at__isnull=True))).annotate(
            sent_latest_message=Subquery(
                ChatMessage.objects.filter(sender=OuterRef('pk')).order_by('-created').values('content')[:1])).annotate(
            sent_latest_message_dt=Subquery(
                ChatMessage.objects.filter(sender=OuterRef('pk')).order_by('-created').values('created')[:1])).annotate(
            received_latest_message=Subquery(
                ChatMessage.objects.filter(recipient=OuterRef('pk')).order_by('-created').values('content')[
                :1])).annotate(
            received_latest_message_dt=Subquery(
                ChatMessage.objects.filter(recipient=OuterRef('pk')).order_by('-created').values('created')[:1]))
```

Comment: Can you share your models and the rest of your query? How do you know that there should only be one seen message, what does `ChatMessage.objects.filter(sender_id=1234, seen_at__isnull=True).count()` return?

Comment: @IainShelvington I've added ChatMessage model and User manager.

Comment: That's a lot of annotations on your default manager, if you remove all of them and just do the one annotation in your example do you get the correct result?

Comment: Nope, it's the same. Moreover, if I change `Count('sent_chat_messages',filter...)` to  `Count('received_chat_messages',filter...)` I get the same result (11).

Comment: @IainShelvington omg, the solution was pretty easy - `.annotate(
            sent_unread_messages=Count('sent_chat_messages',
                                       filter=Q(sent_chat_messages__seen_at__isnull=True), distinct=True))`

Answer (score 0):

can you try using `.distinct()` method (which removes the duplicate elements from a queryset) when getting the messages ?

Comment: I'd like to but where?

Comment: at the end of the queries when getting the messages